# Spring Validation - Programmatically bind to a Validator

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, jackson

I am trying to use Spring validation to validate my model populated by Jackson converter.
So I have a java class,

```
class MyClass(){
    private String myString;
}
```

This class is populated by Jackson and I have the instance in my Java code.
Have also defined a validator class like,

```
class MyValidator implements Validator {
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return MyClass.class.equals(clazz);
    }   
    public void validate(Object object, Errors errors) {
           //Validation logic here
    }
}
```

Now what I wanted to do was to send the object to the validator and get the errors object, examine and proceed further. But, for calling

```
validate(Object object,Errors errors)
```

I need an errors instance which I dont have. I cant use `BindingResult` or `Errors`. Please advise on how to proceed further.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this manually in code with a DataBinder:

```
MyClass toValidate = new MyClass();
DataBinder binder = new DataBinder(toValidate);
binder.setValidator(new MyValidator());
binder.validate();
if (binder.getBindingResult().hasErrors()) {
    // oh noes!
}
```

Although if you've got a @ModelAttribute defined in a @Controller in spring-mvc, something like this should work (placed inside the relevant @Controller):

```
@ModelAttribute("myclass")
public MyClass myClass() {
    return new MyClass();
}

@InitBinder("myclass")
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(new MyValidator());
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/do/something", method = POST)
public ModelAndView validatedRequest(@Valid @ModelAttribute("myclass") MyClass profile,
                                     BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        // oh noes!
    }
}
```

Comment: Eventually I ended up putting all my validations in a seperate class and directly invoked from the model. But the suggestion provided should work for anyone facing the same issue